# Django: extra 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY slows it down. Has no redirect

Tags: django, django-urls

In my webpage JS I do:

```
window.location = /xxx/forum/topics/threads?topicid=0
```

in my urls I have:

```
url(r'^([^//]*)/forum/topics/threads/$', showThreads),
```

showThreads returns a render_to_response. No redirect.

When I look in the network tab I see for Name/path and status:

```
threads
/xxx/forum/topics                 301 Moved permanently

www.mysite.com
/xxx/forum/topics/threads         200 OK
```

Why does it split it into two calls (or whatever they are)? If I copy the url directly into the address bar then it only shows the second call. More importantly, it seems to slow it down by 100ms to do the two calls instead of the one. Not 100% sure about the slower speed. It's a bit different every time.

I do NOT have any urls for just

```
url(r'^([^//]*)/forum/topics/$', yy),
url(r'^([^//]*)/forum/$', yy),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have "APPEND_SLASH = True" in your config file. It will do a 301 redirect to the same URL but with a slash at the end.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Adding en end slash to my urls fixed this.